# Error Name "Your application CheckBox does not contain a definition for Checked" when I try to check the selected item in gridview asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Error Name "Your application CheckBox does not contain a definition for Checked" when I try to check the selected item in gridview asp.net C#

This is my C# code

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdItemList.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkrow=(row.Cells[1].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);
                if (chkrow.Checked == true)
                {
                    string Item = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    string UnitPrice = (row.Cells[3].FindControl("lblUnitPrice") as Label).Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(Item, UnitPrice);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Humm! Please check following things first.

1. Are you binding the Grid on PageLoad?If Yes, then put it in "if(!Page.IsPostBack){BindGrid}".
2. Ensure the Value “chkrow” is not null.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks bro, But I got this error in design time, not run time error